# eb create can't see Unable to assign role, needs to verify that you have permission to pass this role: aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam, aws-roles

I have a node app want to upload it on EB.
after running `eb init` and create the application, tried to `eb create` I got this

```
WARNING: Insufficient IAM privileges. Unable to determine if instance profile 'aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role' exists, assuming that it exists.
Creating application version archive "app-230218_020058149734".
Uploading testEBUdg/app-230218_020058149734.zip to S3. This may take a while.
Upload Complete.
Environment details for: testEBUdg-dev
  Application name: testEBUdg
  Region: us-east-1
  Deployed Version: app-230218_020058149734
  Environment ID: e-spw6eyzmpe
  Platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-1::platform/Node.js 14 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/5.6.4
  Tier: WebServer-Standard-1.0
  CNAME: testEBUdg-dev.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com
  Updated: 2023-02-18 00:01:36.993000+00:00
Printing Status:
2023-02-18 00:01:35    INFO    createEnvironment is starting.
2023-02-18 00:01:37    INFO    Using elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-xxxxxxxxxx as Amazon S3 storage bucket for environment data.
2023-02-18 00:01:38    ERROR   Unable to assign role. Please verify that you have permission to pass this role: aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role.
2023-02-18 00:01:38    ERROR   Failed to launch environment.
ERROR: ServiceError - Failed to launch environment.
```

[Permissions policies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9YTS.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the aws credentials were not configured, so you need to set them up using `aws configure` and the user need to have the appropriate permission and then perform `eb init`.

Comment: that was the issue I completely forgot to run `aws configure` after change user credentials.Thanks